# Convert from binary to XML serialization without needing the type

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0

I have a project with a few types that I binary-serialize (`BinaryFormatter`) to files. I'd now like to create a second project which allows admins to temporarily decode those files into a more readable XML format (e.g., using `XmlSerializer`).

I could deserialize them into an object of the original type, then reserialize them, but is it at all possible to

- skip the deserialization (at least in my own code), and
- better yet, not have to reference the type at all in my decoder tool?

Comment: Do you use .NET's native binary serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to .NET's native binary serialization (`BinaryFormatter`), the problem is that it saves your object (along with all the necessary **metadata** for deserialization) using an **undocumented format** (AFAIK).

If you really want to try doing it without deserialization, you can check [this article](http://primates.ximian.com/~lluis/dist/binary_serialization_format.htm), which appears to have analyzed its format (but the author himself states that it might be incomplete). But my opinion is that it's far too much trouble.

Comment: As a follow-up question: is there a library that will let me do this? For example, will http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ let me serialize to binary, then re-serialize as human-readable *without* the type later?

Comment: I know that [protostuff](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/) can do it, but it's java. And I am *pretty sure* that [protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/) can allow you to iterate through elements without deserializing (but not 100% sure as I haven't used that functionality). I will have to check (or you can post another question for faster feedback).

Comment: @SörenKuklau yes, if you serialize to binary with protobuf-net, you do **not** need that exact same type later, however it would be *easier and more accurate* if you know what it looked like (not necessarily the exact same type), since protobuf is ambiguous without a schema (you can interpret the same data different ways).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that you can deserialize to your type without specifying that type, at least with standard XML serialization, however, as long as the object was serialized using xml, you could use one of many XML reader classes to traverse the object without needing to deserialize it.  Alternatively, if you happen to be serializing to JSON, there are some libraries out there that will deserialize to anonymous types that you can use.

If the type of conversion you are looking for is purely cosmetic (e.g. to make it more human readable), you could write some RegEx to replace the element tags.

Comment: "There's no way that you can deserialize to your type without specifying that type" Are you sure? The binary serialization appears to contain the name of the type in its header. What I'm unsure about is whether it also contains enough metadata to understand the full structure.